# Add array of new columns to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**How do I append a list of integers as new columns to each row in a dataframe in Pandas?**

I have a dataframe which I need to append a 20 column sequence of integers as new columns. The use case is that I'm translating natural text in a cell of the row into a sequence of vectors for some NLP with Tensorflow.

But to illustrate, I create a simple data frame to append:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3),(11, 12, 13)])
df.head()
```

Which generates the output:

[image]

And then, for each row, I need to pass a function that takes in a particular value in the column '2' and will return an array of integers that need to be appended as columns in the the data frame - not as an array in a single cell:

```
def foo(x):
    return [x+1, x+2, x+3]
```

Ideally, to run a function like:

```
df[3, 4, 5] = df['2'].applyAsColumns(foo)
```

[image]

The only solution I can think of is to create the data frame with 3 blank columns `[3,4,5]` , and then use a `for` loop to iterate through the blank columns and then input them as values in the loop.

Is this the best way to do it, or is there any functions built into Pandas that would do this? I've tried checking the documentation, but haven't found anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Pandas has a whole [section of the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) dedicated to merging, joining, and concatenating data together. It would be helpful to see what you've already tried based on your own research. Note that looping is almost never the best option when it comes to pandas

Comment: whats the logic for naming the columns?

Comment: I wasn't going to name them, and just use iloc to index through them

Comment: what if you have say 3 rows, and two lists of data, will row 3 be empty?

Comment: In my use case, I need to pass a function to take a string of text and embed it as a series of 20 floats. Each row needs to be passed through that function before the floats can be determined, so it's more complicated then just merging two lists together

Comment: Can you mimic that in your question

Comment: Okay, I updated the example to reflect the use case btter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

```
def foo(x):
    return pd.Series([x+1, x+2, x+3])

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3),(11, 12, 13)])

df[[3,4,5]] = df[2].apply(foo)

df
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1  11  12  13  14  15  16
```